# How to block robots.txt in your PHP project?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

What is the best way to block and remove this annoying robots.txt file in a PHP project?

Comment: What do you mean "block and remove"?  robots.txt is just a file that instructs search engines how to index your site.  It generally isn't touched by PHP, and certainly doesn't require PHP.

Comment: A human being bothered by the sight of a robots.txt file? This is news to me.

Comment: Malbe I wasn't clear in my question. But for some reason, I don't want to allow every bots to prevent some spammers use it to scan or abuse bandwidth. There's nothing to do with PHP...

Answer (score 1):

The `robots.txt` file is created by the developer of a site.  All the file does is instructs bots like google or yahoo what they SHOULD and SHOULD NOT index on your site for their search engines.  In no way are they bound to follow the instructions but most major ones do.

If you want to tell all robots to not search anything and essentially try to block them enter the below in your `robots.txt` file

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Like I said this is not mandatory for a robot to follow this but all the good bots do.

More info here http://www.robotstxt.org/

Comment: I only want to block a certain abused bots only. Thanks for the link!